# Import custom Vue Component fails in TypeScript

Tags: laravel, typescript, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

The code works, but why does TypeScript not understand my custom Component? And why does it add the `.js` extension to the filename?

```
Could not find a declaration file for module ..
```

I am using Laravel 9, Vue 3, Vite 3, InertiaJS

After hours of searching, I did not find a solution.

[image]

**Component file**

```
<template> </template>
<script>
  export default {};
</script>
```

**tconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom"
        ],
        "types": [
            "vite/client"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["resources/js/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["resources/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Options API or setup(), define your component using `defineComponent` method:

```
<template> </template>

<script>
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

  export default defineComponent({
    // type inference enabled
    setup(), // if using setup()
  })
</script>
```

And if using `<script setup>`, define it like so:

```
<template> </template>

<script setup lang="ts">

</script>
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html
https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent

Comment: Thank you! I actually figured it out before you answered, it was the `lang="ts"` that was missing in my script tag indeed. Thank you for clarifying